# How to test latency and performance of application virtualization?

Tags: performance

I have a solution where user can access desktop application in browser using application virtualization that is implemented with the help of ThinRDP. I would like to know, what is the latency of this solution? How much time will it take to render it on user machine? Average case? worst case?

Please let me know if there is any tool available that can be used for evaluating latency or any other method to do this.

I already tried Wireshark and Microsoft Network Monitor but didn't got appropriate results.

Comment: What will you do with the information?  Do you have specific tolerances that you need to achieve?

Comment: What was inappropriate about the Wireshark/MSM results?

Comment: I want to know how much time will this solution take to render client(browser) screen. I don't have any numbers that I want to achieve.

Comment: I used Wireshark and MS Network Monitor for getting time to render screen but it shows network traffic with lot of information and I am not able to get required time from that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the Statistics tab in Fiddler to inspect the performance of your http(s) traffic. It will be more user-friendly than trying to use WireShark (for most people). Of course you can also use the built in dev tools in chrome, ff and IE since they all have timings for the requests usually in some form of a Network tab. You might also be able to use selenium (or just plain js) to get a true render time vs request/response time. Note: however you probably only care about the request round trip so I would first see if Fiddler works to get some insight on your latency.